# HashMap, maybe atomic when get, and the key is guaranteed already put completely

Tags: java, multithreading

my code:

```
class Pair {
    public String key;
    public String value;
}
Iterator<Pair> pairs;
HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
while (pairs.hasNext()) {
    Pair p = pairs.next();
    map.put(p.ket, p.value)
    // then put p.key to another thread for RPC
    // after returned, lookup the hashmap, join the result and p.value, and output 
}
```

After each RPC finished, the thread pool will lookup the hashmap, to join the RPC result and value for the key.
Is this atomic ?

Answer (score 3):

No, the `HashMap` class is not thread safe. You will need to add additional synchronization.

Comment: Or use one of the convenient thread-safe variants of `HashMap`: [`Collections.synchronizedMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedMap(java.util.Map)) or [`ConcurrentHashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html).

Comment: Obviously, HashMap itsself is not threadsafe, java.util.concurrency provides a lot of data structure for synchronized map. But this case, key is already put into map completely, it's still not threadsafe?

Comment: In this case, read/write to a specified key will never happen simultaneously

Comment: @CharlesWang Not neccesarily, you need to synchronize the insert method.

Comment: Still you could have two writes happening at the same time which would be bad, or a write colliding with a read.

Comment: I considered that, when the capacity of hashmap is not enough, a write will double the capacity, at this time, a read request may be bad, but i am not sure

Comment: I don't think it's worth it to fool around with synchronization by understanding the implementation details of the class. You could get it wrong, or they could change, and you are not talking about a lot of overhead.